# Unpacking Future[Option[MyType]] in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am new to Scala and Play Framework so I am not quite sure what is wrong. I am trying to unpack a Future[Option[MyType]] given by a Slick DB controler (Play Framework). MyType is called BoundingBox in the code:

```
  def getBoundingBoxByFileName(name: String) = {
    val selectByName = boundingBoxTableQuery.filter{ boundingBoxTable =>
      boundingBoxTable.name === name
    }
    db.run(selectByName.result.headOption)
  }
```

BoundingBox type has a field called product_name. To retrieve this field I do the following:

```
  val boundingBoxFutOpt = BoundingBoxQueryActions.getBoundingBoxByFileName("some_file")

  val res = for {
    optBb : Option[db.BoundingBox] <- boundingBoxFutOpt
  } yield{
    for(bb : db.BoundingBox <- optBb) yield {
      println(s"${bb.product_name}")
    }
  }
```

This code does not yield anything on the output, though I have no compilation errors. If I change the println statement for some random text (not using the bb reference), it is also not printed on the console. To me it seems that the println statement is never executed.

I'll appreciate some directions on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your program is terminating before the future has a chance to run the println.  I think this will get you what you want:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

// your code here

Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)
```

In your above example you're running a thread but then not giving it a chance to finish execution.  The above will block until the future is complete.

It's worth nothing that you shouldn't use Await in production code as the blocking done negates the value of having code run in a separate thread.